# How to make from this .hover function a .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do i make from this .hover function a .click function?

```
if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    $('.navbar-main-slide .navbar-nav > .dropdown').hover(function () {
        "use strict";
        $(this).addClass('open').find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
    }, function () {
        "use strict";
        var na = $(this);
        na.find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp('fast', function () {
            na.removeClass('open');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what you've got so far in a JSFiddle so we can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly your question, have you tried to change `hover` to `click` function?

```
if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    $('.navbar-main-slide .navbar-nav > .dropdown').click(function () {
        "use strict";
        $(this).addClass('open').find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
    }, function () {
        "use strict";
        var na = $(this);
        na.find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp('fast', function () {
            na.removeClass('open');
        });
    });
}
```

Or you can try this

```
if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        $('.navbar-main-slide .navbar-nav > .dropdown').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('open').find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(500).slideToggle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your mean works or not? If works you can accept my answer

Comment: yes it works. Sorry i'm new here, i have accepted your answer! =)

Comment: Yes thanks, it can easily help other in future if you accepted my answer, that mean my answer is works